# Pulling a contact's picture isn't working

Tags: java, android, android-contacts

I'm the developer of [Call Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=groovinchip.com.callmanager). I'm having some difficulty adding some new functionality to my app.

Currently, when adding a new call (or editing an existing one), a user can select a contact from their own contact list and the name and phone number will populate the respective fields. I am now trying to retrieve the contact's photo, but it is not working. I've checked out numerous posts and nothing is working.

The current code for retrieving contact info is:

```
// Retrieve the contact data and set name and number to the appropriate fields
private void contactPicked(Intent data){

    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Uri uri = data.getData();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(uri, null, null, null, null);
    cur.moveToFirst();

    String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
    String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
    nameField.setText(name);
    String number = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
    numField.addTextChangedListener(new PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher());
    numField.setText(number);
    numField.addTextChangedListener(new PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher());;
}
```

This works as intended.

The new code, as it currently stands, looks like this:

```
// Retrieve the contact data and set name and number to the appropriate fields
private void contactPicked(Intent data){

    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Uri uri = data.getData();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(uri, null, null, null, null);
    cur.moveToFirst();

    String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
    String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
    nameField.setText(name);
    String number = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

    InputStream photo_stream = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(cr, uri, true);
    BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(photo_stream);
    Bitmap my_btmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(buf);
    try {
        buf.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    numField.addTextChangedListener(new PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher());
    numField.setText(number);
    numField.addTextChangedListener(new PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher());

    Drawable photo = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), my_btmp);
    contactPhoto.setBackground(photo);
}
```

If anyone could please help me with this, I'd appreciate it immensely. Please feel free to examine the code further at the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/GroovinChip/Call-Manager) for further clarification. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Uri contactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, id); // create a plain contactUri from the _ID, instead of using the uri given by Intent data
InputStream input = getContentResolver().openInputStream(contactUri)
Bitmap bmp = null;
if (input != null) {
    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
    input.close();
    BitmapDrawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bmp);
    contactPhoto.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
} else {
    // clear any existing background here if needed
}
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. Also, btw, setBackgroundDrawable is deprecated.